# How to set utf-8 as default encoding for pull request merge conflict extension in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

How to set utf-8 as default encoding for pull request merge conflict extension in azure devops?

Checked the pull request merge conflict extension and azure devops, didn't found any option to set default encoding. How to set this for a repository?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such option can set the default encoding to UTF-8 in Pull Request merge conflict extension.

Currently, the default encoding type is ANSI.

To change the encoding type, we need to manually select the UTF-8 option.

[image]

**Note:** you need to enable the feature: **Use Beta Resolver** in setting option, then you can manually change the encoding type.

[image]

The extension and Azure DevOps doesn't provide the option to change this default behavior.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can report the feature in the [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&ssr=false#qna).